Proof that a group with only characteristic subgroups is abelian with locally cyclic torsion subgroup
I'm trying to understand a proof by Cutolo, Smith and Wiegold that a group $G$ all of whose subgroups are characteristic is necessarily abelian and has locally cyclic torsion subgroup.
I think I understand the abelian part: as characteristic subgroups are normal, $G$ must be Dedekind. So if $G$ were non-abelian, it would be a Hamiltonian group. But by the Hamiltonian group structure theorems of Dedekind and Baer, we'd have $G = Q_8 \times A$ for some abelian subgroup $A$. But there is an automorphism of $Q_8$ swapping $i$ with $j$. This automorphism extends to an automorphism of $G$, which swaps $i$ with $j$ in $Q_8$ and acts as the identity automorphism on $A$ and this isomorphism clearly doesn't fix $\langle i \rangle$, so $\langle i \rangle$ isn't characteristic, a contradiction. So indeed $G$ is abelian.
But I'm not sure I understand the rest of the proof. The authors begin by considering $T$ the torsion subgroup of $G$, and $P$ a primary component of $T$, which I take to mean a maximal $p$-group subgroup of $T$. They then discuss rank without specifying the meaning, but which I gather is the $p$-rank, the maximum rank (as in size of minimal generating set) of an elementary abelian subgroup.
They then state that if $\text{rank}(P)>1$, then $G = U \times V \times W$, where $U,V \leq P$ and $\text{rank}(U)=\text{rank}(V)=1$. They finally conclude that at least one of $\text{Hom}(U,V)$ and $\text{Hom}(V,U)$ is non-trivial, so one of $U$, $V$ is non-characteristic in $G$, a contradiction.
I have a few questions about the missing details to complete the proof. Here's where I'm at so far. As the different primary components of $T$ are $p$-groups for different primes $p$, with $T$ being a direct product of these primary components, and as there are no isomorphisms between non-trivial $p$-groups for different primes $p$, by Goursat's lemma the subgroups of $T$ are all themselves direct products of subgroups of the primary components.
If each primary component were locally cyclic, then $F$, a finitely generated subgroup of $T$, would be a direct product of finitely generated subgroups of the primary components. Then by local cyclicity of the primary components, $F$ is a direct product of cyclic groups of coprime orders, so $F$ is cyclic, hence $T$ would be locally cyclic.
Therefore we need only show each primary component of $T$ is locally cyclic. Then if we consider $F$, a finitely generated subgroup of the primary component $P$, then by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, and given that $P$ is a $p$-group, $F$ is a direct product of cyclic $p$-groups. But if there was more than one factor in $F$, then we'd have $\text{rank}(P)>1$. So provided $\text{rank}(P) \leq 1$, then $F$ is cyclic and $P$ is locally cyclic.
So provided $\text{rank}(P) \leq 1$ for each primary component $P$ of $T$, then $T$ is locally cyclic.
I'm hoping someone can clarify if my thinking is correct in the above, as well as helping me understand why if $\text{rank}(P)>1$, that gives the specified factoring of the whole group $G$, and how one can identify an automorphism which fails to fix one of the factors $U$ and $V$. I intuitively understand that it's trying to do the same thing as I described earlier with the automorphism in $Q_8$, but that required a specific factorisation. In this case I don't know how to construct such a factorisation, and I also lack any specific knowledge of abelian $p$-groups with rank $1$, besides that they are locally cyclic.
